# A symbol of a graph of a function without to use TikZ and similar

Tags: fonts, symbols, packages

From an American textbook I have seen this magenta symbol near to the numbering of an exercise that I liked so much that it represents a generic graphic of a function in a cartesian reference system.

[image]

I did some research but I don't think there is any package that can generate this symbol without `TikZ-pgf`. Here there is my MWE without the curve into grid.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
$\textcolor{magenta}{\mathlarger{\boxplus}}$
\end{document}
```

I have not find a symbol of a curve to overlap to the symbol.

Comment: You can draw it with `tikz` and than define command, which will put it before `\item` number.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi David. Into my previous question I have not put the tag `tikz-pgf` or other.

Comment: why can't you simply use includegraphics?

Comment: With lot of sincerity I would decrease the number of the images for our book. My book compile after 5 minutes because have many images.

Comment: ? one image shouldn't take a measurable amount of time in a book.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use, actually, OS W7 32-bit with 3GB total ram. The images peraphs are close to 100 or more.

Comment: @Sebastiano I don't see that the existing images affect this question. Adding one small tiny image to get the requested marker is unlikely to take any longer than loading an additional package and then plotting that using bezier curves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pict2e`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,pict2e}

\newcommand{\usegraph}{%
  \begingroup\setlength{\unitlength}{0.16pt}%
  \begin{picture}(100,100)
  \color{magenta}
  \polygon(0,0)(100,0)(100,100)(0,100)
  \Line(50,0)(50,100)
  \Line(0,50)(100,50)
  \cbezier(0,0)(60,200)(40,0)(100,100)
  \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\usegraph

\end{document}
```

[image]

A version with a thicker curve:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,pict2e}

\newcommand{\usegraph}{%
  \begingroup\setlength{\unitlength}{0.16pt}%
  \begin{picture}(100,100)
  \color{magenta}
  \polygon(0,0)(100,0)(100,100)(0,100)
  \Line(50,0)(50,100)
  \Line(0,50)(100,50)
  \linethickness{0.8pt}
  \cbezier(1,0)(60,200)(40,0)(99,100)
  \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\usegraph

\end{document}
```

[image: thicker]

With the (rather new) `l3draw` package.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3draw,xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\usegraph}{O{16pt}}
 {
  \raisebox{0pt}[#1][0pt]{\color{magenta}\egreg_usegraph:n { #1 }}
 }

\dim_new:N \l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_usegraph:n
 {
  \dim_set:Nn \l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim { #1 }
  \draw_begin:
  \draw_linewidth:n { 0.025*(#1) }
  \draw_path_moveto:n { 0\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim , 0\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 1\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim , 0\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 1\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim , 1\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 0\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim , 1\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim }
  \draw_path_close:
  \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
  \draw_path_moveto:n { 0.5\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim , 0\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.5\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim , 1\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim }
  \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
  \draw_path_moveto:n { 0\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim , 0.5\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 1\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim , 0.5\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim }
  \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
  \draw_linewidth:n { 0.05*(#1) }
  \draw_path_moveto:n { 0.01\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim , 0\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim }
  \draw_path_curveto:nnn 
    { 0.6\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim , 2\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim }
    { 0.4\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim , 0\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim }
    { 0.99\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim , 1\l__egreg_usegraph_size_dim }
  \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
  \draw_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\usegraph\quad\usegraph[1em]\quad\usegraph[30pt]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for not using tikz:-)

Comment: I have added `\linethickness{1pt}` into you code but increase all the lines.

Comment: @Sebastiano Add it at the proper spot, like in the second example

Comment: Excellent....as always!

Comment: Am loving `l3draw`.