# l3draw diagram interpretation

Tags: draw

I am currently trying to understand the [l3draw](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3experimental/l3draw.pdf) package defined functions and looked at the example:

```
\dim_new:N \l_mypos_dim
\draw_begin:
\draw_path_moveto:n { 0cm , \l_mypos_dim } % Coordinate (0,0) move to 
\draw_path_lineto:n { 1cm , \l_mypos_dim } % (1,0) horizontally.
\dim_set:Nn \l_mypos_dim { 1cm }           % Define the new y-coordinate.
\draw_path_lineto:n { 1cm , \l_mypos_dim } % Draw from (1,0)--(1,1).
\draw_path_close:                          % Close path from (1,1)--(0,0).
\draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
\draw_end:
```

Are the comments the correct interpretation?

My objective is to replicate the answer here: [A symbol of a graph of a function without to use TikZ and similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521924/10898) just for fun.

Comment: Looks about right, but the first is also a draw not a move. So you're drawing `(0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- cycle;` (in the equivalent Ti*k*Z notation).

Comment: @Skillmon On page 10 it says `In general, for reliable treatment
by viewers, a \draw_path_moveto:n operation should precede the first use of a \draw_-
path_lineto:n on a path.`

Comment: Yes, but the comment there is slightly off. It should be `move to (0,0) and draw to (1,0) horizontally`

Comment: The interpretation is correct. I'm not sure what's the real usage of `\l_mypos_dim`

Comment: @azetina See the translation in the new language. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Incredible! :)

Comment: \l_mypos_dim  

    (interpreted as 'my postion dimension'), it is just defining a value in the first line, before the drawing environment.   

In this example it isn't clear if the value is zero. Maybe it is predefined in the code.    

And the command:    

    \draw_path_close:

means the path will be closed connecting to the first defined point.